# GTK TreeView styling

Tags: css, treeview, gtk3, pygobject, gtktreeview

Short version:  What CSS selector can be used to style the background of a GTK TreeView header?

Long version:  I've tried `treeview header`, `treeview header .button`, `.button`, `button`, `label`, `GtkTreeView header`, `header` and `*` as selectors for the header of a Gtk.TreeView.  Of these, `button` works to change the colour of the text in the header (the `color` attribute) but not the background (`background-color`).  `label` changes the colour of the background behind the header text, but leaves a big area around the text at the default.  `*` works, but of course changes everything else, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried to use [Gtk Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Inspector) on a simple python example and it reported the treeview class as .view and the button on the header as .button. Setting a custom css provider to the application with:

```
cssProvider = Gtk.CssProvider()
cssProvider.load_from_path("custom.css")
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), cssProvider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)
```

and the custom.css file with the following content:

```
.view .button { color: Red; background: Cyan; font-weight: bold; text-shadow: none; box-shadow: none; }
```

The result was:

[image: result ui]

Here you can see the treeview header with font color as Red and backgroung as Cyan.

Tested on Fedora 23.

**EDIT**

On Fedora 26, it's as documented. you should use:

```
treeview.view header button { color: Red; background: Cyan; font-weight: bold; text-shadow: none; box-shadow: none; }
```

and the result is similar.

Comment: Check https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html CSS nodes

Comment: Updated URL for the GtkTreeView CSS nodes documentation: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.TreeView.html#css-nodes